# How to Extract Substring in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm processing CSV files in a `foreach` loop to import into a SQL table. The name of the file follows the following pattern:
`anything_name.csv`
Where:

`anything` could be, well, anything, including underscores and dots.

`name` is what I want to extract (in a variable or derived column).

`.csv` will alwyas be there.

Is there a way to do this in SSIS without going to a C# Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can achieve that using a SSIS expression.

Once you have the filename in a dataflow try a derived column with this expression:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FileName),5,FINDSTRING(REVERSE(FileName),"_",1) - 5))
```

Tested with `FileName = Any_thing_123.az_actualname.csv`

The expression returns: `actualname`

This will work if the filename keeps the structure you described.